# How to separate class fields in a namespace-like structure?

Tags: c#

I have this class

```
public class Weapon
{
    //default settings
    public float[] defaultEnergy;
    public UltEvent<Weapon>[] defaultCallbacks;
    public MotionType[] defaultMotions;

    //special settings
    public float[] specialEnergy;
    public UltEvent<Weapon>[] specialCallbacks;
    public MotionType[] specialMotions;
}
```

I would like to separate the default and the special settings in a more organized way in my code.

If I need the default energy, I need to write `weapon.defaultEnergy[i]`.

For organization, I would like to have a syntax similar to a namespace access.

I would like to write `weapon.default.energy[i]` to make it obvious I'm referring to the default settings (and same thing holds for special settings).

Can I have this syntax without creating new classes?

Comment: _"Can I have this syntax without creating new classes?"_ - Kinda: with extension-methods, but I would consider this a bad use-case. Dealing with assorted members in an object is a fact-of-life in programming, get used to it.

Comment: @Dai I was imagining something like creating a namespace inside a class or something that doesn't involve create new unnecessary stuff.

Comment: No, C# does not support anything like that.

Comment: Also, FWIW, your `class Weapon` really should not have exposed mutable fields like that...

Comment: I modified the class for better explaining of the problem.

Comment: There are two _kinda_-ish solutions that achieve the end-result you want, but they do involve defining new types (but they are low-to-zero cost types) instead of being _purely_ syntactic - I can post them in an answer if you're interested...

Comment: Sure. It can help me or others. I'll end up using a class if it's necessary... although I didn't wish to.

Comment: BTW, in C# we use `PascalCase` for public members, not `camelCase`. And you should not expose fields, especially not `T[]` array fields.

Comment: Groups of similar fields like this is the *perfect* candidate for creating a new class. You can call it `WeaponSettings`, and `Weapon` would have two `WeaponSettings` properties, one called `default`, and one called `special`.

Comment: @Sweeper I did think about that, as both groups have the same "shape"), however I didn't want to make that assumption as that would be short-sighted if the `class Weapon` is ever updated to have hetereogenous `Default` and `Special` members.

Comment: They have similar fields, sorry for not mentioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about adding these:

```
public (float[] Energy, UltEvent<Weapon>[] CallBacks, MotionType[] Motions) Default =>
        (defaultEnergy, defaultCallbacks, defaultMotions);
public (float[] Energy, UltEvent<Weapon>[] CallBacks, MotionType[] Motions) Special =>
        (specialEnergy, specialCallbacks, specialMotions);
```

After change:

```
public class Weapon
{
    //default settings
    public float[] defaultEnergy;
    public UltEvent<Weapon>[] defaultCallbacks;
    public MotionType[] defaultMotions;

    //special settings
    public float[] specialEnergy;
    public UltEvent<Weapon>[] specialCallbacks;
    public MotionType[] specialMotions;

    public (float[] Energy, UltEvent<Weapon>[] CallBacks, MotionType[] Motions) Default =>
        (defaultEnergy, defaultCallbacks, defaultMotions);
    public (float[] Energy, UltEvent<Weapon>[] CallBacks, MotionType[] Motions) Special =>
        (specialEnergy, specialCallbacks, specialMotions);
}
```

Then, we can access like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var weapon = new Weapon();
    weapon.defaultEnergy = new float[] {0, 1, 2};

    // access
    Console.WriteLine(weapon.Default.Energy[1]);
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution, although I imagine this implementation has to create this tuple always it's called... It's the simplest solution anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort-of do what you're doing via two separate approaches (and both approaches have minimal-to-zero runtime cost), but both approaches do require defining new types:

### Option 1: Present a zero-cost view of an object with `readonly struct`:

- `readonly struct` types in C# which are simply passed-around or used as values within a method (i.e. are only used as parameters, locals, or return values, but *not* ever used as a field in a `class`) will not be GC-heap allocated (alternatively, you can use `ref struct` to *really* make sure there's no GC heap usage, but `ref struct` types impose their own constraints which may be undesirable in this context).
- Having a property that does `=> new MyStructType()` does not involve the GC heap, despite using the `new` operator, btw.

Like so:

```cs
public readonly struct WeaponDefaultSettings
{
    private readonly Weapon w;

    internal WeaponDefaultSettings( Weapon w )
    {
        this.w = w;
    }

    public float[]            DefaultEnergy    => this.w.DefaultEnergy;
    public UltEvent<Weapon>[] DefaultCallbacks => this.w.DefaultCallbacks ;
    public MotionType[]       DefaultMotions   => this.w.DefaultMotions;
}

public readonly struct WeaponSpecialSettings
{
    private readonly Weapon w;

    internal WeaponSpecialSettings( Weapon w )
    {
        this.w = w;
    }

    public float[]            SpecialEnergy    => this.w.SpecialEnergy;
    public UltEvent<Weapon>[] SpecialCallbacks => this.w.SpecialCallbacks;
    public MotionType[]       SpecialMotions   => this.w.SpecialMotions;
}

public class Weapon
{
    public Weapon( ... )
    {
        this.DefaultEnergy = ?
        this.DefaultCallbacks = ?
        // etc
    }

    public WeaponDefaultSettings DefaultSettings => new WeaponDefaultSettings( this );
    public WeaponSpecialSettings SpecialSettings => new WeaponSpecialSettings( this );

    public float[]            DefaultEnergy    { get; } = Array.Empty<float>();
    public UltEvent<Weapon>[] DefaultCallbacks { get; } = ...?
    public MotionType[]       DefaultMotions   { get; } = Array.Empty<MotionType>();

    public float[]            SpecialEnergy    { get; } = Array.Empty<float>();
    public UltEvent<Weapon>[] SpecialCallbacks { get; } = ...?
    public MotionType[]       SpecialMotions   { get; } = Array.Empty<MotionType>();
}
```

Usage:

```cs
Weapon weapon = ...

Console.WriteLine( weapon.DefaultSettings.DefaultEnergy );
Console.WriteLine( weapon.SpecialSettings.SpecialEnergy );
```

### Option 2: Use `interfaces` to represent different views of the same object

...combined with C# 8.0 DIM, which allows interfaces to have implementations too.

Because these interfaces are implemented, and returned, by a single object instance this approaches does not require any extra GC heap allocations. Whereas if `Weapon` *delegated* any of the interfaces to a different type then it would necessarily have to `new`- it up and cause allocation - even if the implementation was a `struct` (as `structs` passed as an `interface` type will be moved to the GC heap).

```cs
public interface IHasWeaponDefaultSettings
{
    Weapon Self { get; }

    public float[]            Energy    => this.Self.DefaultEnergy;
    public UltEvent<Weapon>[] Callbacks => this.Self.DefaultCallbacks;
    public MotionType[]       Motions   => this.Self.DefaultMotions;
}

public interface IHasWeaponSpecialSettings
{
    Weapon Self { get; }

    public float[]            Energy    => this.Self.SpecialEnergy;
    public UltEvent<Weapon>[] Callbacks => this.Self.SpecialCallbacks;
    public MotionType[]       Motions   => this.Self.SpecialMotions;
}

public class Weapon: IHasWeaponDefaultSettings, IHasWeaponSpecialSettings
{
    private float[]            defaultEnergy;
    private UltEvent<Weapon>[] defaultCallbacks;
    private MotionType[]       defaultMotions;

    private float[]            specialEnergy;
    private UltEvent<Weapon>[] specialCallbacks;
    private MotionType[]       specialMotions;

    Weapon IHasWeaponDefaultSettings.Self => this;
    Weapon IHasWeaponSpecialSettings.Self => this;

    public IHasWeaponDefaultSettings DefaultSettings => this;
    public IHasWeaponSpecialSettings SpecialSettings => this;
}
```

```cs
Weapon weapon = ...

Console.WriteLine( weapon.DefaultSettings.Energy );
Console.WriteLine( weapon.SpecialSettings.Energy );
```